# Construct2 Collisions Gone Weird

Tags: collision, construct-2

I am making an infinite runner, but when I run my character is inside the floor a little bit. I made a new project with the template "Infinite Running", then changed the player graphics.
Picture from Debugger:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPRKH.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You could try and move origin of sprite/anim to bottom of sprite and/or you could use invisible dummy sprite/object for player and then pin the actual player sprite to it. That way collision will behave more predictably.